# I get error 405 after submitting the django form

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-forms

i try to combine DetailView and form, but when i try to submit the form i get a 405 error

views.py

```
class ReplyToVacancy(DetailView):
    model = Vacancy
    template_name = 'vacancies/vacancy.html'
    pk_url_kwarg = 'vacancy_id'
    context_object_name = 'vacancy'
    # form_class = 'CreateApplication'
    # success_url = '/'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['form'] = CreateApplication
        return context
```

html

```
<form  action="" method="post">
                  {% csrf_token %}
                  {{ form.as_p }}
                  <input type="submit">
              </form>
```

Comment: are you trying to submit `csrf_token` and `form.as_p`?

Comment: Use form view https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/class-based-views/generic-editing/

Comment: Error 405 is Method Not Allowed. You send form data with not allowed Post method.